# I want to know how vercel works in relation to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

1. Can I think of Vercel as a framework that makes AWS easier to use?
2. Vercel doesn't use AWS' EC2, is this correct?
3. Assuming that the front server is deployed, I am curious about the difference in the process of deploying Vercel and AWS.

I'm curious about the difference in the principle of operation, not the method, when deployed with vercel and deployed with AWS.

I wonder if you can understand the flow by focusing on which keywords.

Thank you to everyone who took the time to respond.
Sorry for not smartly asking a difficult question.